# Form layout in Visual Studio 2008 (mobile)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm just starting on a quick proof of concept application intended for use on Windows Mobile 6.5 devices. I'm using the Visual Studio 2008 (9.0.21022.8) form designer to create a simple GUI as per the screenshot below.

The first problem is that I can't get the GO button to be the same height as the text box to the left. Regardless of whether snap to grid is enable or disabled, when I adjust the button height, it snaps to a height that is either greater than or less than that of the text box.

The second problem is that I cannot eliminate the vertical spacing above and below the list box. I've seen mention of a "Padding" setting in various MSDN articles but this doesn't appear to be a property of the form or of any component. [Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376622/change-spacing-of-snaplines-in-visual-studio-2008) suggests setting this value under Options->Windows Forms Designer but there doesn't appear to be such an option. Am I missing something obvious or is this just more complicated than I thought?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the Compact Framework. Some things work differently here. In the "large" framework you can change the `IntegralHeight` property for a list box, which is not available in the Compact Framework, so the `ListBox` will snap to the default item height. This may cause the vertical spacing below the `ListBox`. The spacing above the `ListBox` can be eliminated either by manually setting the `Top` coordinate in the `ListBox`'s properties to `Top + Height` of the text box.

As for the button's height: Try to set it manually in the properties. If that doesn't work I suggest you try changing the button's height to the text box height in the form's `Load` event.

Generally I suggest that you change the designer settings (Visual Studio settings) so that the designer doesn't show a grid, but uses the snap lines (Extras > Options > Windows Forms Designer > Layout Mode = SnapLines).

Comment: Excellent, manually setting the Height and Top properties on the components sorts out the problem.