# Is it possible to customize spacing between controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, radio-button

I was wondering if there is any way to get the default text at radio buttons closer to the button. It dosent look like VS has any built in functions for this.

Comment: Which UI framework?  WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Possible dubplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376622/change-spacing-of-snaplines-in-visual-studio

Comment: your question title doesn't match your question content. You mentioned about a particular case in which there are not any different controls involved. I think you mean your `RadioButton` has 2 parts, the `Text` and the `button` (looks like a circle), and your problem is the `text` is too far from the `button` by default, and you want to change this? (make them closer).

Comment: anyway, a screen shot would be better than words in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [**Padding Structure**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.padding.aspx). You can use the [**constructor with 4 parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x17zs1da.aspx)  to assign left, top, right and bottom padding size.

Hope this helps!