# Is there a way to adjust the grid snap for spacing in Visual Studio win form designer?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, label, spacing

I've got a lot of information to display in a small area and I would like to space this text as tight as possible without overlapping. There is a grid snap in the Visual Studio Win Form designer. But, this is what I'm getting:

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the grid snap in the Visual Studio 2010 Windows Form Designer? Or is there a way to make sure that labels are 'leaded' as tight as possible?

Thanks, as always!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: [Change spacing of snaplines in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376622/change-spacing-of-snaplines-in-visual-studio?rq=1)

Apparently, there isn't a 'universal' grid snap. It's adjusted for each item. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TableLayoutPanel` adjust its `Rows` to your requirement (e.g size to absolute 20 pixels), insert `Lables` in each row and adjust `Lable`'s `Anchor`/`Dock`, `Margin`, `Padding`, and `TextAlign`. This is the best you can get with `Winform` I guess. You can also have a look of `WPF` which will give you more control of the *visual* settings.